# Appending Dataset Results to a div with specific requirements

Tags: jquery, web-services, html, dataset, photoswipe

I am currently trying to incorporate 'PhotoSwipe' for jQuery into my application with images that are pulled from a database via a POST to my webservice, and a little serialization magic.

I am still kinda new to jQuery, but I've gotten pretty far considering.

I still have yet to figure out how to use code properly on this site, so here's a pastebin of the code in question:

http://pastebin.com/avSXDDgK

Basically what it does is comb through my dataset, find anything wrapped in an image tag and pull it into a variable. Which it does.

What I have to do, is combine that information, to ultimately form something resembling this:

`<a href="C:/images/full/001.jpg" rel="external"><img src="C:/images/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" /></a>`

So what I need is for someone to show me or point me in the right direction towards a resolution.

Currently all the alerts work for me, however nothing actually happens to the div.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Here is an example of the XML in which my image urls are being pulled from

http://pastebin.com/nnvdKgqV

...and here is a link to PhotoSwipe, they say to use rel="external" within the  tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(data).find('Table').each(function(){
    var tableData1 = $(this); // 'this', in your example, refers to the Table data

```
var image = $(tableData1).find('image').text();
var imagepath = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/' + image + '" </img>' ;

var i = '<img src="' +imagepath+ '</img>' ;
$('#gallery2').append(i)
alert(imagepath);


});


});
```

Thanks @Crab via #jQuery IRC